# Sort list of tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need the first abbreviations(like "VBM") from to_sort to be in the same order as in sort_list

```py
to_sort = [['SSW', 'Sergey Sirotkin', 'WILLIAMS MERCEDES'], ['SVF', 'Sebastian Vettel', 'FERRARI'], ['SVM', 'Stoffel Vandoorne', 'MCLAREN RENAULT'], ['VBM', 'Valtteri Bottas', 'MERCEDES']]

sort_list = [('VBM', '1:12.433'), ('SSW', 'Error time'), ('SVM', '1:12.463'), ('SVF', '1:44.414')]

example = [['VBM', 'Valtteri Bottas', 'MERCEDES'], ['SSW', 'Sergey Sirotkin', 'WILLIAMS MERCEDES'], ['SVM', 'Stoffel Vandoorne', 'MCLAREN RENAULT'], ['SVF', 'Sebastian Vettel', 'FERRARI']]
```

Comment: `to_sort.sort(key=lambda x, l=[i for i, _ in sort_list]: l.index(x[0]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate list of first items of `sort_list` and call `list.index()` to get index of element *(as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74060604/10824407#comment130763642_74060604) comment)*.

```py
to_sort.sort(key=lambda x, l=[i for i, _ in sort_list]: l.index(x[0]))
```

Results of [benchmark](https://tio.run/##vZRRa9swEMff8ymOvNgGE2onjGHwQ9q5EEj2EG/uQwhCxnKr1ZaMooaEsc@eSbaVem2WdXGpISSc7v@/3110rvbygbPx50ocDpKjDRcSQlitrDi@s1ywYiLuyR5iKrh8pEyH7mbz@Wy6iGERLW@iL1FsrV1QguS2EaR4IylmkBApSaFjt9FyOV3OTN6izpM8z0kBCWYZ54IRHVzczKfL6Cuoz/T7/FsjSK5rQYIL5ScoXHMp8aZOPwKsBwONjgq6qflto/ICzx9NxmPLccE2TUVCcAGSlqQNJ53cTya36ccLJpPRxJtYjqqRkRzqOrzYUmZjF1InGACAIPJJsPqMZDr@SPZhgcs0w7BzoQhXFHJVk7qAgDJI1wEUI8oysrN3q6u147w0R5QVlJFODTzSp3YfZzVrQX4gr@MKJa4qyu7V1H5uA6DZrrHLlLm9VaaOdiXsqSQCS2Knzq9adrbjwLiuNML6FMLr/i4lOTGXf9f3u4X/7KUOaV/X/OpY0wAY2cljkn7eQAo0hy2EIVDFY7ROU@AU3YnptG1@GJM6RYjhkiCkkyyESqyuJbIaHFpW@l2hl4jKOlIJyqQ9fL7CQ7c9HjVf3TO7fdm4cNxbR@Vv1D9RhcNc8BJMQVPqWax8X6mVWPWWEhF6V/pR9/4kVDvZc2xm@H0QW48LSc2S/IXyuMYXEhp9T7rzo3y56D1Z32Wg/nlWvyek35PuTQP132eg/n8N9HD4DQ):

```
sort_olvin 0.2418229230097495
sort_olvin_inline 0.22788053899421357
sort_andrej_1 0.2182700579869561
sort_andrej_1_inline 0.19632228900445625
sort_andrej_2 0.5893592859792989
sort_andrej_2_inline 0.5593071450130083
```

First option offered by [@AndrejKesely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74060662/10824407) is fastest, so I *recommend* you to use it, but (if it's not necessary to keep original list) it's a bit faster to use inline `list.sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create mapping where keys are abbreviations and values are positions of these keys:

```py
mapping = {v: idx for idx, (v, _) in enumerate(sort_list)}

out = sorted(to_sort, key=lambda x: mapping[x[0]])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    ["VBM", "Valtteri Bottas", "MERCEDES"],
    ["SSW", "Sergey Sirotkin", "WILLIAMS MERCEDES"],
    ["SVM", "Stoffel Vandoorne", "MCLAREN RENAULT"],
    ["SVF", "Sebastian Vettel", "FERRARI"],
]
```

---

Alternative (without mapping):

```py
out = sorted(
    to_sort,
    key=lambda i: next(
        idx for idx, (v, _) in enumerate(sort_list) if v == i[0]
    ),
)
print(out)
```

Comment: Solution with mapping is [fastest](https://shorturl.at/bdoW8), it could be boosted if using inline `.sort()`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Please post the benchmark as an answer here, I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Done. Cheers to our slovak brothers ;)